react-native Card component with cutout
I need to create a card component, but I know how to add an inset cutout. It may be necessary to use react-native-svg lib, but I am not sure. It's like a separator between the header and the dynamic content
Please help
export const Card = styled.View`
  padding: 16px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
`;



